How can I get the website URL using Voiceflow Chatbot?
I'm trying to add a feature to my Voiceflow chatbot where I can save as a variable the website URL. I need it for the chatbot flow so it should be saved as a variable inside the flow.
I tried using the javascript module:
websiteURL = window.location.href

It says that window is not defined.
I also asked to the AI Voiceflow Assistant an it told me to modify the launching code to get the url as a variable, it didn't work neither.
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(d, t) {
      var v = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
      v.onload = function() {
        window.voiceflow.chat.load({
          verify: { projectID: 'XXXXCURRENT_IDXXXX' },
          url: 'https://general-runtime.voiceflow.com',
          versionID: 'production',
          variables: {
            websiteURL: window.location.href
          }
        }).then(() => {
          setTimeout(function() {
                  window.voiceflow.chat.open();
                }, 200);
        });
      }
      v.src = "https://cdn.voiceflow.com/widget/bundle.mjs"; v.type = "text/javascript"; s.parentNode.insertBefore(v, s);
  })(document, 'script');
  </script>```




Any luck so far? Need something like that too!

There is some guidance in the documentation on how to add custom variables. https://developer.voiceflow.com/docs/customization-configuration
  (function(d, t) {
  var v = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
  v.onload = function() {
    window.voiceflow.chat.load({
      verify: { projectID: 'XXXXCURRENT_IDXXXX' },
      url: 'https://general-runtime.voiceflow.com',
      versionID: 'production',
      launch: {
        event: {
            type: "launch",
            payload: {
            websiteURL: window.location.href
            }
        }
        },
        autostart: false
    });
  }
  v.src = "https://cdn.voiceflow.com/widget/bundle.mjs"; v.type = "text/javascript"; s.parentNode.insertBefore(v, s);})(document, 'script');

You'll want to take out the variables part and replace it with a launch event and set your websiteURL as a variable there.
That should pass the value to your last_event system variable upon load. Then use the JavaScript Code step to validate the payload values and set existing variables with default values at the start of each new conversation.
if (last_event) {
  websiteURL = last_event.payload.websiteURL
} else {
  websiteURL = "i dunno"
}

Make sure that websiteURL is a variable that is already created in your agent. Use the javascript code step immediately after the start step and this should set the websiteURL variable to the current page whenever the app is reloaded.

This really worked. The key is to make sure you add the javascript step right after start trigger, otherwise it won't work.
